# In finite groups, is the inverse function composable from product?

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that in finite groups, one can compose the inverse operation from the product operation? I recall somewhere reading that in finite groups, the inverse $x^{-1}$ is a positive integer power of $x$, hence is composable from product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true. If $G$ is a finite group and $x\in G\setminus\{e\}$, there is some natural number $n$ such that $x^n=e$ and that $x^{n-1}\neq e$. But then $x.x^{n-1}=e$ and therefore $x^{n-1}$ is the inverse of $x$.

Comment: And we can use a single $n$ for all $x\in G$. Namely, $n=|G|$.

Comment: It might help to note that this makes use of the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: It is beyond me why high rep users indulge in stunning displays of banality like this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is banal for me and for you, but not for the person who asked it.